# Keeping a local storage database up to date

Tags: local-storage

I am curious about client-side local storage databases and how to keep them up to date with a remote source.

My understanding is on first visit to your site, you could create a database in the user's browser with local storage from a source file.

However, the local database copy might require updating at a later date if the remote source changes. The simplest way would be forcing the user to completely redownload the source if their copy is out of date.

What would be better is if just the new/updated data could be downloaded and patched onto the local database.

Are there any examples of this kind of process in action?